# Type determined return values

Tags: javascript, error-handling, callback

I have the following js code:

```
if (typeof errorCallback === "function") {
    var result = errorCallback.apply(this, arguments);
    // if errorCallback returns a non-false value, end execution
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }
}

// if there's no errorCallback or errorCallback returned 'false',
// 'null', 'undefined', '', 0, hell-knows-what-else ...
// note, that we don't return anything here
defaultErrorCallback.apply(this, arguments);
```

So far I came up with this:

```
return (typeof errorCallback=== "function"
    ? errorCallback.apply(this, arguments)
    : void 0) || defaultErrorCallback.apply(this, arguments);
```

But this will return (in some cases) the result of `defaultErrorCallback` whereas I want it to return `undefined`.

Can this code be shortened without changing functionality?

Comment: Why do you want to shorten it? I see no reason for it at all. I would rather chance the whole idea of returning undefined at all unless it is not for compatibility/legacy reasons.

Comment: I want to know whether I can shorten it or not, without any specific reason. Name it curiosity. And the code base is so big that I can't (don't want to bother?) change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you you started with is pretty good.

Since you are looking for shortest code I'll go for code-golf:

You can replace `void 0` with `false`, `null` or, even shorter, just `0` (since it will just drop the flow of execution through to the final part of the code).

Replacing `errorCallback` with `e` and `defaultErrorCallback` with `d` and removing unnecessary whitespace then you get:

**92 Characters:**

```
return(typeof e=="function"?e.apply(this,arguments):0)||(d.apply(this,arguments),undefined);
```

Answer (score 2):

More of a golf question than a CodeReview question really,

I would first consider

```
return (c
  ? someFunc.apply(this, arguments) || undefined
  : undefined)
```

The interesting part is that if otherFunc is not a function, then you would have executed it as a function anyway.. 
Furthemore,

- I like better `someFunc instanceof Function` than `typeof someFunc === "function"`
- For something this fancy I would go for the Spartan `f`
- I tend to avoid `void` except for bookmarklets

so perhaps something like this:

```
//Unless f is a function and returns a non false value, return undefined
return (f instanceof Function ? f.apply(this, arguments) : undefined ) 
       || alternativeFunction.apply(this,arguments );
```

Comment: But `otherFunc` is not executed here, right? This piece is crucial

Comment: One more thing. Is `f(this, arguments)` equivalent to `f.apply(this, arguments)`? Isn't `f` called with the global context in the first example?

Comment: My bad! Well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [code piece](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/68516/56764) by konijn I came up with the shortest version of the code that works exactly the same as in question:

```
return (f instanceof Function
        ? f.apply(this, arguments) || undefined
        : undefined)
            || (o.apply(this, arguments) ? undefined : undefined);
```

Tried to indent it to make everything clearer than it is. The `(o ? undefined : undefined)` part is pretty weird, though.

Comment: Thanks for running with this, I clearly did not have my coffee yet :) Question : how come your are not sure about `f` being a function, but you are sure that `o` is a function?

Comment: `o` is defined in the same file just above, and `f` is passed as a parameter.